# Dynamic Combobox ListFillRange without VBA

Tags: excel, dynamic, combobox

I have an Excel Document that I need to deploy **without VBA** to my coworkers. I have a Combobox in one of its sheets that I want to populate dynamically. The content of the combobox is the result of a data query from a different workbook, so the number of lines may vary.

I created a temporary sub just to asign the ListFillRange. I have added all different attempts that I tried so far without success...

```
Sub SetListFillRange()
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=MyQueryTable[SomeColumn]"
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=TestName" 'A named Range pointing to MyQueryTable[SomeColumn]
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=[TestName]"
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "='SheetX'!A2:INDEX('SheetX'!$A:$A,COUNTA('SheetX'!$A:$A))"
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=OFFSET('SheetX'!A2,0,0,COUNTA('SheetX'!$A:$A) - 1,1)"
End Sub
```

The point why I'm trying to use the ActiveX ComboBox is the autocomplete feature which is missing in the form ComboBox that comes with Excel (in fact you may not type text into it at all...).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an ordinary Excel table you could use `List` instead

```
Sub SetListFillRange()
    ComboBox1.List = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("SomeColumn").DataBodyRange.Value
End Sub
```

If you want to use ListFillRange you could try

```
ComboBox1.ListFillRange = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("SomeColumn").DataBodyRange.Address
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the List-property. But both your suggestions only create hard copies from the QueryTable so there will be no dynamic changes to my ComboBox at all.

Comment: How do you refresh the query?

Comment: Automatically, every 5 minutes (setting in the query properties), but the actual data will not change that often... The problem is, once the document is deployed, I will no longer have writing rights to the path where it's stored as I'm just assisting in the upgrade process. So building the list for the ComboBox has to be a "future proof" mechanism.